# Torrent clients for Mac other than uTorrent

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, torrent

Can someone recommend a good torrent client for the Mac, other than uTorrent?

[The only problem I have with uTorrent is that occasionally it doesn't respect the upload limit. This is a known issue, and no setting seems to fix it in my case.]

I am looking for these features:

1. Ability to select files to download (in case of multi-file torrent) BEFORE the download begins
2. Show transfer rates in the dock icon
3. Assign relative priorities to files within a torrent
4. Good, clean UI (optional)
5. No bloatware/adware like a built in media player, ads, yahoo-search-plugins, etc (optional)

Comment: I believe SE sites do not permit requests for software recommendations.  Is that not the case for the Apple SE site?  (NOT that I'm complaining.  That rule is kind of lame, and this is a useful question.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I highly recommend the open source client [Transmission](http://transmissionbt.com).

[image]

Features:

> - The Mac OS X interface is written in Objective-C
> - Shows transfer rates in the dock icon
> - Uses Growl notifications and dock badging to keep you informed.
> - Download/Upload Prioritization

---

Other:

> - Doesn't bundle toolbars, pop-up/flash ads, social tools, or any other useless crap.
> - It doesn't hold some feaures back for a payware version.
> - Its source code is available for anyone to review.
> - Doesn't track users, and their website/forums have no third-party ads or analytics.

I've been using Transmission for many years and can't imagine using anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Does it have all/most of the features listed in the question above?

Comment: Yes, it has all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Try Tribler, designed to fight censorship by using built-in anonymity:

[Tribler.org](http://www.tribler.org)

There is an article about it here:

[Anonymous and impossible to shut down](https://torrentfreak.com/bittorrent-anonymous-and-impossible-to-shut-down-141218/)

It's open source too.

Comment: I was looking for something like this, not famous but good and os.

Answer (score 3):

Try [qbittorrent.org](http://www.qbittorrent.org)

It does all the things you asked for, except showing the transfer rates in the Dock icon. But I didn't check for this option very thorough, it might have it :-)

One of the best features for me is that it can download a file in sequential order (think of a video that you can start watching it, before the download finishes 100%).

Comment: This is great. Unlike µTorrent, it actually *works* on my machine, unlike Vuze, it has no bundled adware, and unlike Transmission (my otherwise favourite), it supports connecting via a proxy. It's nice and lightweight, too.

Answer (score 0):

One more venerable classic client is [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/).

Completely free from advertising and unwanted plugins, and has a focus on providing features the community needs, such as private downloads, password protection, and scheduling and bandwidth options.

Supports a range of plugins that expand its functionality. The plugins can utilise privacy blocklists (which you shouldn't rely on), labelling, scheduling and notification options. You can monitor folders for files, and add them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

#### What about [**Aria2**](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/aria2)?

Being command-line based it's perhaps the most lightweight and powerful tool, and it's not only for Torrent but for file downloads in general.

Very easy to install:
(if you have the popular [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager)

```
brew install aria2
```

and very easy to use:

```
aria2c TORRENTFILE
```

You will be surprised by how easy and how fast it downloads the files. For advanced users, it has also many useful options, e.g. to attempt to download fragments of files in some specific order (e.g. to be able to watch a video while downloading it).